# Downloading R in Ubuntu Issues

Tags: r, ubuntu, download

I am trying to install R in Ubuntu 11.04. I tried to do this 
in the Synaptics manager. However when I chose r-base-core, I got the following:

> r-base-core:  Depends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed 
>   Depends: gfortran  but it is not installable  Depends: libblas-dev 
>   but it is not installable or      libatlas-base-dev but it is not going
>   to be installed  Depends: liblapack-dev  but it is not installable or 
>     libatlas-base-dev but it is not going to be installed  Depends:
>   libncurses5-dev  but it is not installable  Depends: libreadline-dev 
>   but it is not installable  Depends: libjpeg62-dev  but it is not
>   installable  Depends: libpcre3-dev  but it is not installable 
>   Depends: libpng12-dev but it is not going to be installed  Depends:
>   zlib1g-dev  but it is not installable  Depends: libbz2-dev  but it is
>   not installable  Depends: dpatch  but it is not installable

I also did this in the GNOME terminal with "sudo apt," again getting the same result.

When  I typed in "cat " I got

> ## deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 *Natty Narwhal* - Release i386
>
> (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted
>
> ## See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade
>
> to
>
> ## newer versions of the distribution. deb
>
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted deb-src
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
>
> ### Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
>
> ### distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>
> natty-updates main restricted deb-src
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
>
> ### N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the
>
> Ubuntu
>
> ### team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive
>
> any
>
> ### review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb
>
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe deb-src
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe deb
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe deb-src
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
>
> ### N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the
>
> Ubuntu
>
> ### team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself
>
> as to
>
> ### your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
>
> ### multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
>
> ### security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty
>
> multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty
>   multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates
>   multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates
>   multiverse
>
> ### Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the
>
> 'backports'
>
> ### repository.
>
> ### N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
>
> ### extensively as that contained in the main release, although it
>
> includes
>
> ### newer versions of some applications which may provide useful
>
> features.
>
> ### Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any
>
> review
>
> ### or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
>
> ## deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main
>
> restricted universe multiverse
>
> ## deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main
>
> restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
>   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main
>   restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security
>   universe deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security
>   universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security
>   multiverse deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security
>   multiverse
>
> ### Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
>
> ### 'partner' repository.
>
> ### This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical
>
> and the
>
> ### respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
>
> ## deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
>
> ## deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
>
> ### This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
>
> ### developers who want to ship their latest software. deb
>
> http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main deb-src
>   http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main deb
>   http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu natty/ deb-src
>   http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/

Note that I have already added the R repositories at the bottom.

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Read the detailed instructions at this [README](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) which worked for thousands of users.  Add the `apt-get` sources entry for your flavour, run `apt-get update` and then install.

If that fails, we need better error messages with more details of **what** you did **how** than just the output above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are missing some basic repositories for ubuntu. If Dirks answer does not help, please let us know which ubuntu you are using, and your sources, i.e. the output from

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and, if there are any files related to R in

```
ls /etc/apt/sources/sources.list.d/
```

their content as well.

Comment: Yeah I think I am missing some files in Ubuntu. When I typed in